# How do I send multiple unrelated emails with swiftmailer?

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I'd like to have an email queue that is processed via cron, sending out emails every 30 seconds, limiting the emails sent to 100. The swiftmailer documentation doesn't make it clear how to accomplish this in a single SMTP connection. I know I would basically need to reset all of the message and attachment parameters, but would like advice regarding where and what to loop.

For instance, do I need a new mailer for every email:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance( $params['smtp_host'], $params['smtp_port'] )
   ->setUsername( $params['smtp_user'] )
   ->setPassword( $params['smtp_pass'] );
foreach( $emails as $email ){
  $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance( $transport );
  //...
  $this->reset();
}
```

or can the same mailer be used for multiple unrelated emails? Do I actually need a new transport for each email:

```
foreach( $emails as $params ){
  $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance( $params['smtp_host'], $params['smtp_port'] )
     ->setUsername( $params['smtp_user'] )
     ->setPassword( $params['smtp_pass'] );
  $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance( $transport );
  //...
  $this->reset();
}
```

I couldn't find an example of this anywhere I looked online.

EDIT:
From my own testing, it would seem that I need a new transport instance for every email. Is this true, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your SMTP server. But if you use a cronjob which sends 100 emails all 30 seconds then you probably only need one mailer and one transport instance. Then you can create multiple message objects inside one loop like this:

```
// Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('****', 25);
//$transport->setUsername('****');
//$transport->setPassword('***');
$transport->setUsername('***');
$transport->setPassword('***');
// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$db = createDB();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM emailQueue WHERE send = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ORDER BY id LIMIT 5";
$result = $db->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  // Create the message
  $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();

  // Give the message a subject
  $message->setSubject($row['subject']);

  // Set the From address with an associative array
  $message->setFrom(..);

  // Set the To addresses with an associative array
  $message->setTo($$row['receiver']);
  ..

 // send message
 $mailer->send($message);
}
```

However many SMTP servers have limits on the number of messages that may be sent during any single SMTP connection. If your close to that limit (100 might be a realistic limit) then you should reconnect before that limit is reached. That can be easily achived with the [anti-flood plugin](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html#antiflood-plugin) from swiftmailer.

The only reason I can think of to create a new `$message` objecte for each loop is if you have attachments. Otherwise, you just need one `$message` object and you can switch receipt, sender, subject and body text inside the while loop.